# Can't make jQuery Dropkick work

Tags: jquery, html

When I click - it doesn't do anything.

Html code:

```
     <fieldset>
      <form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="example_form">
        <select name="country" class="default" tabindex="2">
          <option value="">Try Me!</option>
          <option value="AU">Australia</option>
          <option value="CA">Canada</option>
          <option value="DE">Germany</option>
          <option value="JP">Japan</option>
          <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="US">United States</option>
        </select>       
      </form>
    </fieldset>
```

js code:

```
     $('.default').dropkick();
```

Don't have any errors in Google Chrome console.

**EDITED**

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.2', 'jquery.validate.min','jquery.dropkick-1.0.0','application' %>
```

Comment: Did you imported jQuery libs?

Comment: Yes. I have other js working. No, I don't have errors.

Comment: Have you included jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js AND https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js in your page?

Comment: Reminded me of chuck norris `$(chucknorris).dropkick()`, anyway, I think you forgot to include the required files, also check your browser console for any errors :)

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.2', 'jquery.validate.min','jquery.dropkick-1.0.0','application' %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the code in jsfiddle.net. It worked fine. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guanxiaohua2k6/36pkP/, where I used

```
jquery 1.7.2
jquery.validate 1.9
jquery.dropkick 1-0.1
```

You can confirm them in "Manage resources" tab.

Comment: I didn't change any code. I think maybe the versions of js libraries were wrong. Can you use the exact same js files with me.